# Aligning an icon font glyph alongside text

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-browser, icons

I'm doing a website, and I'm having some trouble with icon alignment. I have researched everywhere for a solution, and one has not been forthcoming.

Essentially, every time I use an icon and make it smaller than the main text (say, 14px), the icon is forced down by a couple of pixels, and if I keep it the same size, it isn't forced down, but instead extends downwards. This can be corrected with `position: relative; top: [pixels]px;`, but that feels dirty. I have tried vertical align baseline and middle, and I've tried some other things too.

Here's an example with the icon made smaller than the text:

[image: Incorrect Alignment]

And here is an example with the icon the same size as the text.

[image: Incorrect Alignment]

The problem is minor, but the icon should be aligned alongside the text. It would seem a lot of people have this problem, but no solution has worked for me.

What is the solution? Should I consider images instead of icon fonts? Or SVG, perhaps? I suffered the same problem when I attempted to use SVG icons instead.

Comment: Have you tried line-height CSS property ?

Comment: @Iddz I have, and unfortunately it's had little effect, in fact managing to push it down further when increased.

Comment: you can add the icon & text in two separate span & according add margin top to each of the span

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I blamed the font. Now, with further work, it appears the font is partially to blame - odd sizes of font throw things off and require tweaks to get elements to line up. So, there's always the option of tweaking the font itself.

If the font still isn't working, or if you can't edit the font, a `<span>` with `position: relative;top: -1px` (or any other px/em/rem value, until it looks right) does the trick. But this isn't very cross-browser friendly - in Firefox, this got things looking right, and the same in IE and Edge. But in Chrome, everything was off by 0.5-1px.

Bizarrely, the CSS reset doesn't seem to fix that.

Comment: Could you update and improve this answer with specifics of the right and wrong ways you tried? That would be much more helpful than vaguely advising to'double-check the font'. Check for what?

Comment: @djangodude I thought I'd fixed it since it seemed alright at the time, but it's still not working right. I'm going to update it once I have a concrete solution, but currently this is proving a very annoying problem. You'd think there'd be an easier way to align things with CSS!